# MSVCP100.dll cannot be found

Tags: dll

I have installed windows 7 on my external hdd. When I installed a game and tried to run it, it said msvcp100.dll is missing. I can see msvcp100.dll inside system32 folder. I have search the web and found that most people really missed the file, this is different with my case. Anyway, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong folder, it is c:\windows\syswow64 for most games.  This question is not on topic here.

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for posting my question here

Answer (score 1):

The fix is here. Download & install. It appeared because you didn't have Visual C++ installed.
[Microsoft Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: It is VC 10 runtime distributable. Normally the game should install it. So of it is missing it is the games fault.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although another solution would be to run as admin this command 'sfc /scannow'